# Can I run :make without moving the cursor?

Tags: external-command

I use the mapping `nnoremap <leader>m :w \|silent make\|redraw!\|cw<CR>` which allows me to run make while I am editing a file by pressing `<leader>m`.

It annoys me that if my cursor is in the middle of a line when I run this command, after the command finishes, my cursor is moved to the start of the line.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? I noticed that even when I run `:make`, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Go out with a bang

From [:help :make](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake):

> 7. If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.

Running `:make!` will execute the command given by `'makeprg'` (just as `:make` does), but will not jump to the first position in the quickfix list. Thus, your cursor position remains intact.

The quickfix list will still be populated. Just as after running `:make`, `:cfirst` will jump to the first position; `:copen` will open the quickfix window; etc.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way to fix this using the built-in `:make` command. I decided to install  [Neomake](https://github.com/benekastah/neomake) instead, with the mapping `nnoremap <leader>m :w\|:Neomake!<CR>`. This fixed my issue.

Comment: It looks like this command is following the behavior of `:make` in terms of how `!` works. It seems that `:make!` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! If you write this as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.